# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null on web page

Tags: javascript

I try to make my image slide graggable with mouse events but I get thsi error on my web page. How can I solve this problem

My javascript code below here;

```js
var slider = document.querySelector('card-slider-wrapper');
let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDown = true;
  slider.classList.add('active');
  startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  console.log(startX);
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.remove('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  isDown = false;
  slider.classList.add('active');
});
slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDown) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
  const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
  slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Missing class or ID identifier,

Should be either

```
document.querySelector('.card-slider-wrapper')
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#card-slider-wrapper')
```

Comment: I know but when I add identifier, th's error still continue